# EEA family permit refusal - How to satisfy officer with my circumstances

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am Pakistani Resident and my Brother is an EEA with pre settled status in UK. I applied for EEA Family Permit along with my Family (my wife and two sons) and got a refusal. Although i did provided my brother's birth certificate. The decision in the letter states below:

> The Decision
>
> You have advised your EEA sponsor is a Dutch national. You have
> supplied a Dutch passport as evidence.
>
> NOTICE OF IMMIGRATION DECISION In compliance with the Immigration
> (Notices) Regulations 2003 made under section 105 of the Nationality,
> Immigration and Asylum Act 2002 REFUSAL OF EEA FAMILY PERMIT
>
> - On your application you state that your sponsor has resided in the UK    since 15 August 2017 and that you are financially dependent on
>   them.    As evidence of this you have provided various money transfer
>   remittance receipts from your sponsor to you, however, it is noted
>   that these transfers are dated immediately prior to your application
>   (within the last 4 months). Unfortunately, this limited amount of
>   evidence in isolation does not prove that you are financially
>   dependent on your sponsor. I would expect to see substantial evidence
>   of this over a prolonged period, considering the length of time your
>   sponsor has been resident in the United Kingdom.
> - You have advised your family has only recently became dependent on    your EEA sponsor due to a loss of income. We would not consider this
>   as a dependent as this is a recent and possible temporary situation.
> - In addition to money transfer receipts, this office would also expect    to see evidence which fully details yours and your family’s
>   circumstances. Your income, expenditure and evidence of your
>   financial position which would prove that without the financial
>   support of your sponsor your essential living needs could not be met.
> - As evidence of your relationship with your sponsor you have provided    a NDARA family registration certificate. Such documents
>   are not    accepted as proof of relationship as they are produced
>   based on    information given by the applicant. Therefore I am not
>   satisfied that    you have provided sufficient documentary evidence to
>   support your    stated claim that your sponsor is your brother as
>   claimed. The    department would expect to see your birth certificates
>   for you and    your sponsor to establish this relationship.
> - On the evidence submitted in support of your application and on the    balance of probability I am not satisfied you are dependent on your
>   sponsor. I am therefore not satisfied that you are an extended family
>   member in accordance with Regulation 8(2) of the Immigration
>   (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016.
>
> I therefore refuse your EEA Family Permit application because I am not
> satisfied that you meet all of the requirements of regulation 12 (see
> ECGs EUN2.23) of the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations
> 2016.

I did provided an Official Government Document detailing about my family tree, although i didn't provided my birth certificate. Now my question is how do i provide evidence about me and my family's circumstances, as stated above about my income and expenditure, as i have lost my job and i am totally dependent on my brother.

Answer (score 14):

The first two paragraphs of the refusal notice cover the key point: UK immigration does not consider that a short period of unemployment necessarily implies financial dependence. There is a world of difference between that and your brother just helping out.

For that reason alone another application in the near future is unlikely to be successful.

There is no indication here of how long a period of unemployment would be required. Indeed, no such guideline may exist: your circumstances will be considered as a whole, which brings us to the third paragraph.

You have failed to document your financial circumstances in sufficent detail. The officer expects to see a detailed breakdown of your financial commitments including, but not limited to, rent or mortgage payments, other debt repayments, regular expenditure on everyday needs (groceries, clothes, etc.) and any other commitments, along with details of any other income you might have. Without this he cannot fully assess the degree of dependence and another application is likely to fail without it.

Lastly, the document showing your relationship with your brother is not accepted by UK immigration. You should include both your birth certificates in a future application.

Comment: @Matthew I'd interpreted that to mean that the OP lost his job within the last four months and the payments from his brother started at that point.

Comment: So for the financial circumstances, do i need to show receipts of the rental payments, and the groceries, as the rental payments are normally paid out in cash, and i use my debit card for groceries and other items, which are clearly mentioned in the bank statement i provided. Is there any way i can add more detailed which is acceptable by the ECO? As i am totally dependent on him. My Parents applied with the same documents i provided and they got the VISA back in November 2019.

Comment: You are missing the point. The ECO observes that until recently you were working and weren't dependent. He considers that you can work again, and thus will not be dependent again. You must prove that any income you can generate will not cover your needs. This is much easier for elderly retired parents than it will be for a sibling with a young family. Read the first two paragraphs of my answer again. I don't believe you can get this visa.

Comment: Ok, I got your point, that it's highly unlikely that i can get this visa. But what if we assume that i have been dependent for a prolonged period of time, and in that case how do i prove through any documents or evidence that whatever i generate is not enough to cover my needs? What documents are considered a valid evidence?